# Wrong data is assigned to Datagridview at runtime C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datagridview, datatable, datasource

Basically, we have two datagridviews whose Datasource is being assigned at runtime with separate Datatables. There is a common Database class for fetching data from database using stored procedure and common lock object for ensuring concurrency.

But data is being swapped at runtime without any errors.

Any suggestions?

Update :

```
    DataTable table1 = Global.DatabaseMethod.y(0, "ALL", DateTime.Now); 
            DataGridView1.DataSource = table1;  

    lock (_sqlConnection)   
                {   
                    return y(para1,para2,para3, ref _sqlConnection);
                }   

    DataTable table2 = Global.DatabaseMethod.q(0);  
            DataGridView2.DataSource = table2;  

    lock (_sqlConnection)   
                {   
                   return q(para1, ref _sqlConnection);
                }

public static DataTable y(int Para1, string Para2, DateTime Para3, ref  SqlConnection sqlConnection)
{
            try
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("storedProc1", sqlConnection);
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(DbConstants.At + DbConstants.Para1, SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Para1;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(DbConstants.At + DbConstants.Para2, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Para2;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(DbConstants.At + DbConstants.Para3, SqlDbType.Date).Value = Para3;
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(data);
            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogWriter.WriteToErrorLog(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name + GeneralConstants.COLON +
                   MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + GeneralConstants.COLON + ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
```

}

public static DataTable q(int para1, ref  SqlConnection sqlConnection)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("storedProc2", sqlConnection);
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

```
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(DbConstants.At + DbConstants.para1, SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = para1;

            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(data);
            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogWriter.WriteToErrorLog(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name + GeneralConstants.COLON +
                   MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + GeneralConstants.COLON + ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Data from DataGridView1 is displayed on DataGridView2.

Comment: Could you show your code ?

Comment: why are you assigning the datasource to the gridview on runtime. just create 2 different datasources and asign them before runtime

Comment: There are two different datatables assigned to different datasources. But using single database method to fetch data from database.Why is there swapping between two gridview?